# Error while running function using class in python

Tags: python, oop

I have written a below code

```
class new:
   def read_data(self):
       try:
            print("hi")
            with open("D://pythoncsvinflux//csvdatapyconfig.json") as f:
                self.data = json.load(f)
            self.path = self.data['path']
            self.pathtoexe = self.data['pathtoexe']
            os.chdir(self.path)
            os.system(f"{pathtoexe}.exe")
            self.filename = self.data['Tablename']+'.csv'
            self.filenamepath = path +'//'+ filename
            time.sleep(10)
      logs.....

   def run_code(self):
       self.read_data()
       print("hello")
a=new()
a.run_code()
```

When I run the code "hi" is getting printed, but from next line code is not getting executed. Function runs completely, "hello" is getting printed too.. if I execute normally, it works fine. but after converting to class, it is not giving output
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you determining that the next line is not getting executed? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: if that line gets executed, it will generate a csv file in a folder..it is not getting generated

Comment: actually entire function runs.. but it is not giving me any output.. ```   def run_code(self):
       self.read_data()  print("hello"). if I write code like this, it will print hello

Comment: "That line" (ie next one after `print`) is **reading** a file, not generating anything. Do you mean the `os.system` line? If so, how do you know the preceding lines are executed?

Comment: yes.. actually everything below 'hi' is not generating any output. it will dodge those lines and it print "hello"

Comment: @phoenix but you don't have any commands that generate output below the `print("hi")`. If you `print(self.path)`, do you get a valid output? what is the last line that doesn't work for you?

Comment: what happens in that line is ```os.system(f"{pathtoexe}.exe")``` when this line gets executed, it is supposed to create a csv file in a folder. after printing 'hi', it prints 'hello' without generating a csv file as required

Comment: Add some additional print statements to your function; I assume the file *is* being created, just not where you expect it to be.

Comment: according to u, is the code I have written correct?

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. To start, `f"{pathtoexe}.exe"` should raise a `NameError` since `pathtoexe` is not defined, but there's no way to tell how it's being handled since the `except` statement is missing.

Comment: thanks wjandrea :) I got solution for my problem. If u can add in answer, il upvote it

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @wjandrea, The problem was solved by changing

```
os.system(f"{pathtoexe}.exe")
```

to

```
os.system(f"{self.pathtoexe}.exe")
```

thank you :)

Comment: I think the reason this was more difficult for you to debug is because your code was catching and not reporting the actual error.

Comment: @jordanm Yeah, that's the real problem here